# How to use vector plot and gradient vectors?

Tags: plotting

How do I plot a sampling of gradient vectors for fby using the vectorplot command? I’m confused how to use both these commands. [image]

Answer (score 6):

```
f[x_, y_] := (4 x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
VectorPlot[Evaluate@Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], %]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The default presentation of `VectorPlot` has evolved on Mathematica Version 12.1 .
 Now it gives :

[image]

A lot of possibilities of tuning have been added too.

An overview of the state of the art :

```
f[x_, y_] := (4 x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
VectorPlot[Evaluate@Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ContourLabels -> True], %]
```

[image]

Comment: How would you find the exact critical points?

Comment: @calculusbuff39 Try `FindRoot` with initial guess read of from the plots.