# Inconsistent Vector Plot over Contour Plot

Tags: graphics, vector

I am trying to plot  the gradient vector field over the contour plot of a function. While the demo function seems to work very well with the demo taken from [How to use vector plot and gradient vectors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184129/how-to-use-vector-plot-and-gradient-vectors) (first plot), I am getting a quite confusing vector plot with my own function (second plot). My gut feeling is that the vector should be orthogonal to the contours like the ones in the first plot.

Am I doing anything wrong here? I tried quitting the kernel and restart a new one to avoid any carry-over effects from my previous environment but no luck.

[image: screenshot]

```
\[Beta]=0.5; dH =1.5; dL =1; rL = 1;
g[\[Gamma]_,rH_]:=((dL (-1+\[Beta])-dH \[Beta]) (-dH (1+rL) (-1+\[Beta])+dL (1+rH) \[Beta] (1+rH \[Gamma])))/(dH dL (-1+rL (-1+\[Beta])-rH \[Beta]))
VectorPlot[Evaluate@Grad[g[\[Gamma],rH],{\[Gamma],rH}],{\[Gamma],0,1},{rH,1,5}];
Show[ContourPlot[g[\[Gamma],rH],{\[Gamma],0,1},{rH,1,5}],%]
```

---

It seems that it has something to do with the aspect ratio. If I specify the AspectRatio -> 5 in the contour plot, the vector field seems correct. I am able to get a sensible plot by manually multiplying the gradient in y axis by 10 (since specifying AspectRatio -> 5 actually gives you 1:10 visual aspect ratio).

I am still interested in what's behind the scene. It is a bug?

[image: manual fix]

Comment: Please post the code instead of just the image.

Comment: @C.E.Thanks for reminding. Added it in last edit.

Comment: What happens if you use `AspectRatio -> Automatic` or a domain whose side-lengths are equal?  Orthogonality is not preserved if the axial directions are scaled by different magnitudes.

Comment: @MichaelE2 There is no problem when the side-lengths are equal. I think Mathematica gives the wrong vector plot when the side-lengths are scaled by different factors. The arrows are not pointing to the correct directions.

Comment: No, the problem is that when the scaling factors are different, angles are not preserved. It's not the fault of *Mathematica*. It's how geometry works. You have to use the same unit length on each axis to get an accurate picture of the angles. (Of course, it is possible that *M* has miscomputed the vectors, but I doubt it's likely.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think you are right!

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a good question that might help others in the future. If you want to, you might consider answering it yourself now that you have a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @MichaelE2 's answer,

> The problem is that when the scaling factors are different, angles are not preserved. It's not the fault of Mathematica. It's how geometry works. You have to use the same unit length on each axis to get an accurate picture of the angles.

It is a misconception that the the vectors should be always orthogonal to the contours. However, "Orthogonality is not preserved if the axial directions are scaled by different magnitudes."

So Mathematica actually gives the right figure, and my manual adjustment was actually wrong!